# Verification of unpaid volunteer experience, USA

Tags: volunteering

Background information:

I have been working for the last two months for a startup. However, the startup has funding problems and is unable to pay me. I am planning to join some other organization soon.

Question(s):

Since I am unpaid, I am assuming that I would be considered a volunteer. What happens usually in the USA? In this case, is my future employer expected to verify this volunteer experience? If yes, how?

Comment: This seems to be identical to your other question: [Verification of employment for stealth mode startup, USA \[unpaid\]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162428/verification-of-employment-for-stealth-mode-startup-usa-unpaid)

Comment: I removed this question from the previous post. The "volunteering" component makes it an independent question.

Comment: `1.` Not getting paid doesn't make you a volunteer, it makes you an unpaid employee. `2`. Why would you even bother putting this on your resume? If you do put it on your resume, you don't need to say anything about not being paid, that's none of anybody's business. `3.` At the very least, you aren't a volunteer so don't state that on your resume.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I think in the USA, an "unpaid employee" is illegal, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I have already done some non-trivial work for the startup. They did not pay me but that does not trivialize the work. I have dedicated considerable time for the work. It kept me busy for weeks/months and was my primary occupation. The moment I mention this on my resume, I'll be supposed to provide "employment verification". Hence I am asking all these questions.

Comment: OK, but being an unpaid employee doesn't make you a volunteer. You don't need to mention anything about not being paid when asked about this job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @joeqwerty. Yes, I got your point and can't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with US systems for volunteer work. But in general, I'd assume volunteer work not to have any expected compensation (other than having materials plus other costs of working covered). It is also custom practice that volunteer work only exists in non-profit organizations.

At a startup or in any for-profit endeavor, you either get paid money or equity (so shares on the company or options to buy them at fixed price at a term). And being paid equity only is pretty much a red flag. More than that, there is some legal paperwork that a non-profit organization should have (I'm not aware of US legislation, but think about what you'd need to open a bank account owned by the organization).

If they don't have money to pay you, either demand a "co-founder" status, with equity payments or agree on an interest rate your delayed payments will be paid and that they become guaranteed by the shareholders (meaning, you can later charge them in court). Be reasonable and nice, don't expect an answer within the hour but make clear than stalling too much is unacceptable (I'd say one month until a long term solution can be agreed upon and signed on).

That being said, if you personally need monthly payments, make it clear to your pseudo-employers and ask them to write recommendation letters (I'm sure you've taken note of the *"Be reasonable and nice"* part of the last paragraph), they should include e-mail addresses and phone contact, possibly some ID number.

That should cover your needs for being recommended and with negotiating a long term solution for the current status. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mefitico. This sounds reasonable. Still I need to know what usually happens in the USA.

Comment: I'm certain there's a legal definition of volunteer work and I'm certain that this isn't that. If you're concerned about your pay and your legal rights then contact an attorney, but don't call this volunteer work. You weren't brought on as a volunteer, you were hired as an employee with the expectation of being paid for your work. The fact that you weren't paid doesn't make you a volunteer, in word or in deed.

Comment: That is absolutely right, @joeqwerty